# boost::python::extract fails to extract shared base pointer

Tags: python, c++, boost, shared-ptr, boost-python

I'm trying to do a simple derived pointer to base pointer conversion which is a normal behavior in pure C++.
But, dealing with boost::python, to get the same behavior during python to C++ conversion fails on extraction step. Boost::python::extract fails to extract shared base pointer from a shared derived pointer.
Here is the source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

class A {
    public:
        A() : m_int(10) { }
        A(int numb) : m_int(numb) { }
        int get_m() const { return m_int; }
        virtual ~A() {}
    private:
        int m_int;
};

class B: public A {
    public:
        B() : A(100) {}
};

using BPtr = boost::shared_ptr<B>;
using APtr = boost::shared_ptr<A>;
using AContainer = std::vector<APtr>;
using AContainerPtr = boost::shared_ptr<AContainer>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const A& obj) {
    out << obj.get_m();
    return out;
}

APtr CreateA() {
    return boost::make_shared<A>();
}

BPtr CreateB() {
    return boost::make_shared<B>();
}

AContainerPtr CreateEmptyAContainer() {
    return boost::make_shared<AContainer>();
}

void PushBack(const AContainerPtr& cont, const bp::object& obj) {
    bp::extract<const APtr&> a_obj(obj);
    if (a_obj.check()) {
        cont->push_back(a_obj);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Non A object!!!\n";
    }
}
void ext(const bp::object& iterable) {
    bp::handle<> iter_ptr(PyObject_GetIter(iterable.ptr()));
    PyObject* item_raw_ptr = PyIter_Next(iter_ptr.get());
    bp::handle<> item_ptr(bp::allow_null<>(item_raw_ptr));
    while (item_ptr.get()) {
        bp::extract<const APtr&> ex(item_ptr.get());
        if (ex.check()) {
            std::cout << "APtr extracted!\n";
        } else {
            bp::extract<const BPtr&> ex(item_ptr.get());
            if (ex.check()) {
                std::cout << "BPtr extracted!\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << "Failed to extract!!!\n";
            }
        }
        PyObject* item_raw_ptr = PyIter_Next(iter_ptr.get());
        item_ptr = bp::handle<>(bp::allow_null<>(item_raw_ptr));
    }
}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
    bp::class_<A, APtr, boost::noncopyable>("A", bp::init<>())
        .def("__init__", bp::make_constructor(CreateA))
        .def(bp::self_ns::str(bp::self))
        ;

    bp::class_<B, bp::bases<A>, BPtr, boost::noncopyable>("B", bp::init<>())
        .def("__init__", bp::make_constructor(CreateB))
        ;

    bp::class_<AContainer, AContainerPtr, boost::noncopyable>("AContainer", bp::no_init)
        .def("__init__", bp::make_constructor(CreateEmptyAContainer))
        .def("__iter__", bp::iterator<AContainer>())
        .def("__len__", &AContainer::size)
        .def("append", PushBack)
        ;
    bp::def("ext", ext);
    bp::implicitly_convertible<BPtr, APtr>();
}
```

Compiling it with gcc(g++ (GCC) 5.2.0) on linux and using it in this way in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import example
b = example.B()
print b                         # 100
print type(b)                   # <class 'example.B'>
print isinstance(b, example.B)  # True
print isinstance(b, example.A)  # True
l = [b]
example.ext(l)                  # BPtr extracted!

cont = example.AContainer()
cont.append(b)                  # Non A object!!!
```

I'm getting the results shown in comments. Although expecting "APtr extracted!" to be printed on example.ext([b]) function call and not complaining on const.append() function call by putting "b" into cont.

Even adding implicitly_convertible<>() did not help.

Could you please specify what is being done wrong in this scenario?

I tried surfing the net on this issue, but practically in all cases derived class was defined in python and the solution was to call super().**init** function.

**Edit**

I know that changing return value of CreateB() function (*constructor*) to return shared pointer to base will do what I want it to do.
But that's not what I want to do manually since this is a trivial derived to base pointer casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a long investigation, I came to the answer that only returning a shared pointer to base solves the issue.
Anyway, thanks for trying to help.